# Highly extensible open-source web desktop

Tags: open-source, web-apps, node.js, self-hosted, operating-system

I'm looking for a fully-fledged web desktop with all rendering done client-side.

## Details

### Constraints

1. **Extensibility** - it should be easy to add a new application to the web desktop.
2. **Customizable** - it should be easy to change the entire look of the desktop.
3. **Node Compatibility** - I'm using a node server, so I should be able to start and control the web desktop easily from node.
4. **Apps** - there do not need to be any by default
5. **Lightweightness** - it does not need to be lightweight, but it must not be unnecessarily slow/RAM-hungry

### Operating System

Well, it's not really an operating system, but it should run well on all current Gecko and Chromium-based browsers.

### What I have

Right now, [OS.js](https://github.com/os-js/OS.js) is the best I can find, but the only thing stopping me from using it is that my server serves files in a different format, and their FS API isn't documented. Almost every other one I have seen is either closed-source, or hard to run on a node server.

### Intent

I just need a highly configurable web desktop.

### Budget

0, it should be open-source.

Comment: @Izzy I've edited it a little, would you mind telling me what I still need to include?

Comment: Thanks! For node.js I'd say it might not need a specific "OS requirement" (unless that's required for the apps it should run) – but what I still miss is what features you need. If that's just me (and should be very obvious to everyone using such a "web desktop"), please let me know, and I'll remove this comment. Possible examples: Specific apps shipping with it or be able to add to it (I don't know about dependencies here), easy branding/customizing. lightweightness.